# how to properly inject singleton EJB in web service

Tags: java, web-services, intellij-idea, soap, jboss

I have a problem using EJB in my webservice. When I'm trying to call webmethod in my client application, I have NullPointerException errors indicating that my EJB is null.
I am using wildfly-10.1.0-Final server.

My EJB class:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ParkEJB {
 private Map<Integer,Spot> zone;

    public ParkEJB(){
     zone = new HashMap<Integer,Spot>();
     zone.put(1, new Spot());
    }
    public void takePlaceAtIndex(int placeID){
     Spot spot;
     if((spot = zone.get(placeID)) != null)
        spot.setFree(false);
    }

}
```

Spot class:

```
public class Spot{
 private boolean isFree = false;
 public Spot(){}
 public void setFree(boolean free){
    isFree = free;
 }
}
```

Web service:

```
@WebService()
public class Service {
 @EJB
 private ParkEJB park; 

 @WebMethod
 public void takePlace(int placeID){
     park.takePlaceAtIndex(placeID);
 }
}
```

web service client:

```
public class ServiceClient {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
     Service service = new ServiceService().getServicePort();
     service.takePlace(1);
  }
}
```

When I run ServiceClient.main I have:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: java.lang.NullPointerException Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:193)
at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:126)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:252)
at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:181)
at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:262)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:128)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.takePlace(Unknown Source)
at example.ServiceClient.main(ServiceClient.java:8)
```

What am I doing wrong? Why my EJB is being null?

Comment: Have you checked the wildfly logs (stdout/stderr) for any further clue?

Comment: @Bajal Logs don't say much. When I used intellij debbuger it just shown that ParkEJB is null.

Comment: @agaha Can you post the code for new ServiceService().getServicePort() please?